# How to programmatically fire a MouseEvent to a MouseListener with Java?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtree, mouselistener

I have a `JTree` with a custom associated `MouseListener` (for showing popup etc.). I need to fire a `MouseEvent` that will be caught by the `MouseListener`. How should I do that programmatically?

Comment: what are you tried, because JTree has implemented own Listeners invoked by Mouse and KeyBoard http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could create your own MouseEvent and loop through all the listeners and make the call.

For example:

```
MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(tree, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 1, false);
for(MouseListener ml: tree.getMouseListeners()){
    ml.mousePressed(me);
}
```

Comment: +1 - IMO this approach is preferable to emulation of native system events.

Answer (score 3):

The [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class might be what you're looking for.

> This class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed. The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of Java platform implementations.